# Breaking head over how to get position of token with a rule - ANTLR4 / grammar

Tags: parsing, listener, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I'm writing a little grammar using ANLTR, and I have a rule like this:

```
operation   : OPERATION (IDENT | EXPR) ',' (IDENT | EXPR);
...

OPERATION   : 'ADD' | 'SUB' | 'MUL' | 'DIV' ;
IDENT       : [a-z]+;
EXPR        : INTEGER | FLOAT;
INTEGER     : [0-9]+ | '-'[0-9]+
FLOAT       : [0-9]+'.'[0-9]+ | '-'[0-9]+'.'[0-9]+
```

Now in the listener inside Java, how do I determine in the case of such a scenario where an operation consist of both IDENT and EXPR the order in which they appear?
Obviously the rule can match both
`ADD 10, d`
or
`ADD d, 10`
But in the listener for the rule, generated by ANTLR4, if there is both `IDENT()` and `EXPR()` how to get their order, since I want to assign the left and right operands correctly.

Been breaking my head over this, is there any simple way or should I rewrite the rule itself? The `ctx.getTokens ()` requires me to give the token type, which kind of defeats the purpose, since I cannot get the sequence of the tokens in the rule, if I specify their type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
operation : OPERATION lhs=(IDENT | EXPR) ',' rhs=(IDENT | EXPR);
```

and then inside your listener, do this:

```java
@Override
public void enterOperation(TParser.OperationContext ctx) {
  if (ctx.lhs.getType() == TParser.IDENT) {
    // left hand side is an identifier
  } else {
    // left hand side is an expression
  }

  // check `rhs` the same way
}
```

where `TParser` comes from the grammar file `T.g4`. Change this accordingly.

Another solution would be something like this:

```
operation
 : OPERATION ident_or_expr ',' ident_or_expr
 ;

ident_or_expr
 : IDENT
 | EXPR
 ;
```

and then in your listener:

```java
@Override
public void enterOperation(TParser.OperationContext ctx) {
  Double lhs = findValueFor(ctx.ident_or_expr().get(0));
  Double rhs = findValueFor(ctx.ident_or_expr().get(1));

  ...
}

private Double findValueFor(TParser.Ident_or_exprContext ctx) {
  if (ctx.IDENT() != null) {
    // it's an identifier
  } else {
    // it's an expression
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clean solution. I just used something like this :             `int exprpos = ctx.children.indexOf (ctx.EXPR(0));` and
`int identpos = ctx.children.indexOf(ctx.IDENT(0));` to get their relative positions after checking if either are null or not. I think your method is much better. Thanks for the quick response. I think I will use the first solution, since that will not change the grammar rule. Due to my low reputation, I am unable to add your reputation, but clicked on accept answer.

Comment: You're welcome @hari. Don't worry about rep points, your 'thanks' is much more valuable to me.